# Boost, asio, https, and host/certificate verifcation

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I'm looking at Boost's [SSL Client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/ssl/client.cpp). There's a reference to OpenSSL in the comments (sorry, no line numbers):

```
// The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
// being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
// the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
// documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
// for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
// certificate authority.
```

Proper OpenSSL use and verification can be tricky. From experience, I know I have to perform the following to use the library correctly:

- Disable SSLv2, SSLv3, and Compression on the Context object
- Provide the proper root certificate for chain building and checking
- Call `SSL_get_peer_certificate` and verify the certificate is non-NULL
- Call `SSL_get_verify_result` and verify the result is `X509_V_OK`
- Perform name matching (CN or SAN must match requested host)

OpenSSL 1.1.0 will provide name checking, but its only in HEAD at this point in time. From the [OpenSSL Change Log](http://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html):

```
Integrate hostname, email address and IP address checking with certificate
verification. New verify options supporting checking in opensl utility.
```

And:

```
New functions to check a hostname email or IP address against a
certificate. Add options x509 utility to print results of checks against
a certificate.
```

I don't see where Boost is performing any of the configurations or checks in the client code.

What precisely is Boost configuring, and what is it checking or verifying in its `asio` library component when using SSL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**: The Boost callback function, from the link you cited, doesn't verify anything. It returns whatever preliminary verification result was supplied to it by OpenSSL (via `bool preverified`). If there is any fine grained verification required (like the CN match, etc.), it has to be done explicitly by the callback.

**Long answer**: By the time the OpenSSL (or the Boost wrapper for OpenSSL) calls the verification function, in this case, `bool verify_certificate(bool preverified, boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)`, a set of preliminary (or mandatory) verification is already done by OpenSSL. This is explained in the [documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html).

> The certificate chain is checked starting with the deepest nesting level (the root CA certificate) and worked upward to the peer's certificate. At each level signatures and issuer attributes are checked. Whenever a verification error is found, the error number is stored in x509_ctx and verify_callback is called with preverify_ok=0. By applying X509_CTX_store_* functions verify_callback can locate the certificate in question and perform additional steps (see EXAMPLES). If no error is found for a certificate, verify_callback is called with preverify_ok=1 before advancing to the next level.

The documentation also cites an example of how a more fine-grained verification callback could be written. You can draw inspiration from that depending on what your needs are.

**EDIT:** To be sure that Boost's internal callback function doesn't do anything special other than calling the application callback function, I took a look at [engine.ipp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0_beta1/boost/asio/ssl/detail/impl/engine.ipp), the C++ module that invokes OpenSSL's `SSL_set_verify` to set up callback functions. Take a look at how `verify_callback_function` is implemented. It simply invokes the application callback.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply/thumbs up. Stackoverflow changed something with their site, and their page is now broken under the EFF's [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). I had to wait until I got on a different machine.

Comment: I believe it is broken even if you implement the callback. I'm fairly certain `SSL_get_peer_certificate` still needs to be called (even though the callback is invoked);  `SSL_get_verify_result` still needs to be called (even though the callback is invoked); and both happen outside the callback.

Comment: Nothing, in my understanding, is broken. The callback is called after OpenSSL does the preliminary verification. The callback is called with the preverification status to allow the application to finally decide whether to accept the certificate or not. If you don't have anything more to verify, you don't even have to implement the callback. ``SSL_get_peer_certificate`` and ``SSL_get_verify_result`` are helper functions to aid you in getting additional information about the certificate and verification process. It has nothing to do with callback. This is how OpenSSL without boost works as well.

Comment: "The callback is called after OpenSSL does the preliminary verification." - If the server does not offer a certificate, then the callback is never called and `SSL_get_verify_result` returns `X509_V_OK`. In this case, someone must call `SSL_get_peer_certificate` and verify the certificate is non-NULL. I don't see where a user can call `SSL_get_peer_certificate` (since its abstracted away). That means `asio` has to do it. (BTW, we don't call `SSL_get_peer_certificate` from the callback. I'm not even sure we can since we need the `SSL* ssl` object). Or did I miss something?

Comment: If the server doesn't provide a certificate, then what's the point of calling ``SSL_get_peer_certificate`` and why should the certificate be non-NULL? You call ``SSL_get_peer_certificate`` when you want more information about the remote side. For instance, logging purposes or if you want to get fields within the certificate and have a more stringent verification process. Also, the callback is passed an instance of ``verify_context`` from which you can get an instance of ``X509_STORE_CTX`` (``ctx.native_handle()``)from which you can get all the certificate attributes.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply Karthik. "If the server doesn't provide a certificate, then what's the point of calling SSL_get_peer_certificate and why should the certificate be non-NULL?" - the certificate will be NULL if an anonymous protocol is used, such as `ADH`. There is a verify flag, `SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`, but its ignored on the client. See [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html).

Comment: For my ref - comments are talking about desiring a null cert to be failed which seems to equate to `boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert`  rather than `boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer` which allows null cert.

Comment: You have to OR `verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert` and `verify_peer` together.